# Python code perform text to column and new column header name follow previous column content

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone can please help how to write Python code to split one column to multiple column by | then each new column header name follow previous new column content. Your help is much appreciate. Thanks.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TfOE.png)  << using below proposal still not able resolve. Need all expert help advice.

I able to split text to column but header name not able auto grab from previous column content.

Comment: Still not able to resolve my issue and data return not use previous value as my next column header

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```py
original_content= 'A|10.5|B|12'
content = original_content.split('|')

result = zip(content[0::2], content[1::2])
print(list(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def split_column(df,col,sep="|"):
    l = df[col].str.split(sep)
    for col_name, values in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]):
        df[col_name] = values
    df = df.drop(columns=col)
    return df

split_column(df,"Orignal")
```

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFlZo.png)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're asking:

```
old= 'A|1|B|2|C|3'
new = old.split('|')
final=new[::2],new[1::2]
print(f"{final[0]}\n{final[1]}")
```